# Found cell name isn't the same as the on in Google sheets

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, gspread

I'm using gspread to edit my google sheet but I'm having some trouble with the cell name call out.

---

I use this code to find and show what cell the word 'LOCATE' is in:

```
cell_list = worksheet.findall('LOCATE')
print(cell_list)
```

getting the result:

```
[<Cell R12C1 'LOCATE'>]
```

I'm using cell 'A12' for testing so I see 'R12C1' stands for Row 12 Column 1

I've have success writing to that cells using the code:

```
worksheet.update_acell('A12', "TEST")
```

however if I try to test editing the cell 'R12C1' with this code it doesn't work:

```
worksheet.update_acell('R12C1', "TEST")
```

---

Is there a way I can instead have the 'findall' function return and 'A12' style cell name call out?

---

I'm using this for now but it feels a bit sloppy and was wondering if anyone has any tips?

```
alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
deconstruct = str(cell_list[0:1])
row_value = deconstruct[8:10]
col_value = alphabet[(int(deconstruct[11:13])-1)]
cell = col_value + row_value
worksheet.update_acell(cell, "TEST")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this answer?

When I saw [the script of gspread](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/blob/50c5d888bd1f8ba1d2800bdfa7cf6cd785852c24/gspread/models.py), `findall` retrieves the values of the sheet using the method of spreadsheets.values.get of Sheets API and the value is searched from the retrieved values which is an 2 dimensional array. So in this case, the coordinates of the cells are returned as the R1C1 type. If you want to retrieve the A1Notation, I think that your script can be useful.

In order to use the values retrieved by `findall`, if you want to make the script be more simple, how about using `update_cell` or `update_cells` instead of `update_acell`? In this case, the sample script is as follows.

### Sample script:

At the following sample scripts, it supposes that the worksheet has a cell including the value of `LOCATE`.

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the cell coordinate is retrieved from `cell_list`.

```
cell_list = worksheet.findall('LOCATE')

value = cell_list[0]
worksheet.update_cell(value.row, value.col, 'TEST')
```

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the cell retrieved by `findall` is updated.

```
cell_list = worksheet.findall('LOCATE')

cell_list[0].value = 'TEST'
worksheet.update_cells(cell_list)
```

### Note:

- These sample scripts supposes that you have already been able to put and get values for Spreadsheet using gspread.

### References:

- [gspread/models.py](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/blob/50c5d888bd1f8ba1d2800bdfa7cf6cd785852c24/gspread/models.py)
- [update_acell(label, value)](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=update_acell#gspread.models.Worksheet.update_acell)
- [update_cell(row, col, value)](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=update_acell#gspread.models.Worksheet.update_cell)
- [update_cells(cell_list, value_input_option='RAW')](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=update_acell#gspread.models.Worksheet.update_cells)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: This is perfect!
I was messing around with the 'value.row' & 'value.col' after I posted this but couldn't get them working right! This was just what I was looking for thank you so much! :D

Comment: Hey @Tanaike thanks again for the help! Sorry for not accepting your answer. I'm very new and when I couldn't find a button marked 'accept answer' I thought I was just supposed to upvote it. I feel like a fool but had to look it up! Now that I know it's quite obvious but as a new user it just kind of got lost in the clutter lol

Comment: @NIS3R Thank you for your response. It's no problem. I think that your question and solution will be useful for users who have the same issue.